# Cross Platform .NET/Mono Application Development

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I am interested in starting to learn [C#] .NET and wanted to check whether my understandings are correct. I'd like to create GUI-based programs for Windows, but be able to port them someday to other platforms (e.g., Mac, iOS). I realize there's a huge learning curve going from Windows to iOS, and that I will not be able to simply 'write once and compile anywhere'. I'm looking at C# .NET; it has a large support community and my workplace has a VS site license. I'm thinking I can create relatively small, fast Windows executables (*Is that correct?*) and (b) using Mono (and Xamarin, I guess) use at least some of the code later if I create versions of my apps for Mac and/or iOS. (*Is that correct?*)

If the answers to my other questions are "yes," what can I do from the get go to increase the likelihood I'll be able to use my code on more than Windows? (*e.g.*, "just use MonoDevelop" or "use only .NET 2.0 libraries"). I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793013/best-practices-for-net-mono-cross-compiling), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462829/library-compatibility-between-c-sharp-net-vs-c-sharp-mono), [this](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/application-portability/) and [this](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/) but some of this is beyond me right now. I'm a hobbyist, a newbie really, so I struggle a little sometimes to understand the plethora of info I can find on the web.

Comment: With an MVVM approach I think you can get a long way there. Xamarin.Forms (for iOS and Android), WPF (?) and WinForms for (Windows, Linux, Mac). http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/winforms/   and take a look at http://reactiveui.net/ as your MVVM framework which supports all of that.

Comment: MVVM=Model-View-ViewModel ... I'll learn more but, briefly, is this more or less the same as other approaches where model and view code is kept independent?

Comment: Somewhat. MVVM is the go-to approach in non-web applications because it practically keeps all logic out of the UI layer which makes it a lot easier to bolt on other UIs while keeping the core untouched (in best case scenario).